# loop over 2 arrays and make a single array as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

I have 2 arrays of objects which are named `ProductColor`, `Profile`, in this both arrays common value is `fieldname`, here what I'm trying to get done is creating a separate array with few elements from both arrays, below is a detailed array and expected array

**array1**

```
var Profiles = [
{ 
 fieldname: 'Black',
 filename: 'Blackcolor1630667241215.JPEG',
},
{
  fieldname: 'Black',
  filename: 'Blackcolor1630667241217.JPEG',
},
{
  fieldname: 'White',
  filename: 'Whitecolor1630667241218.JPEG',
},
{
  fieldname: 'White',
  filename: 'Whitecolor1630667241219.JPEG',
 }
]
```

**array2**

```
var productimg = [{
  keyId: 0,
  objId: 0,
  fieldname: 'Black'
 },
{
  keyId: 1,
  objId: 0,
  fieldname: 'Black'
},
{
  keyId: 0,
  objId: 1,
  fieldname: 'White'
},
{
  keyId: 1,
  objId: 1,
  fieldname: 'White'
}]
```

**Tried**

```
const finalImgset = [];
    Profiles.map((val) =>{
        productimg.map((img) =>{
                console.log(val.fieldname, img.fieldname);
                if(val.fieldname == img.fieldname){
                    finalImgset.push({
                        src: val.filename,
                        objkey: img.objId,
                        keyId: img.keyId,
                    })
                }
        })
    })
```

but this is not working as expected, here is my expected output

```
var finalarray =  [
 {
  filename: 'Blackcolor1630667241215.JPEG',
  keyId: 0,
  objId: 0,
  fieldname: 'Black'
 },
{
 filename: 'Blackcolor1630667241217.JPEG',
 keyId: 1,
 objId: 0,
 fieldname: 'Black'
},
{
  filename: 'Whitecolor1630667241218.JPEG',
  keyId: 0,
  objId: 1,
  fieldname: 'White'
 },
{
 filename: 'Whitecolor1630667241219.JPEG',
 keyId: 1,
 objId: 1,
 fieldname: 'White'
}]
```

any helps are suggestions are really appreciated,

Comment: The file names do not match from your original data to your expected output. Is this intentional? Am I misunderstanding? Last entry: `filename: 'Whitecolor1630667241219.JPEG'` becomes `filename: 'Whitecolor1630667020772.JPEG'`

Comment: hi @LaytonGB i updated my array, please check now

Comment: `both arrays common value is fieldname`, but the `fieldname` is not unique, how do you merge the item if they both have same `fieldname`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the max length array and loop over that, using the index to merge the two array objects, like this:

```js
const array1 = [
  {
    fieldname: "Black",
    filename: "Blackcolor1630667241215.JPEG"
  },
  {
    fieldname: "Black",
    filename: "Blackcolor1630667241217.JPEG"
  },
  {
    fieldname: "White",
    filename: "Whitecolor1630667241218.JPEG"
  },
  {
    fieldname: "White",
    filename: "Whitecolor1630667241219.JPEG"
  }
];

const array2 = [
  {
    keyId: 0,
    objId: 0,
    fieldname: "Black"
  },
  {
    keyId: 1,
    objId: 0,
    fieldname: "Black"
  },
  {
    keyId: 0,
    objId: 1,
    fieldname: "White"
  },
  {
    keyId: 1,
    objId: 1,
    fieldname: "White"
  }
];

const maxLength = Math.max(array1.length, array2.length)
const finalArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
  finalArray.push({
    ...(array1[i] ?? {}),
    ...(array2[i] ?? {}),
  })
}

console.log(finalArray);
```

Here's a more generic merge function:

```js
function mergeArrayOfObjects(...arrays) {
  let maxLength = 0;
  for (let i = 0, length = arrays.length; i < length; i++) {
    maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, arrays[i].length);
  }
  const finalArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
    const mergedObject = {};
    for (let j = 0, length = arrays.length; j < length; j++) {
      Object.assign(mergedObject, arrays[j][i] ?? {});
    }
    finalArray.push(mergedObject);
  }
  return finalArray;
}
```

Pass as many arrays into the `mergeArrayOfObjects` as needed:

```js
console.log(mergeArrayOfObjects(array1, array2, array3));
```

Comment: the max length and the for loop isn't necessary

Comment: It is if you don't want index out of bounds runtime errors. This is the most performant way to merge the two array objects.

Comment: How does the `...` and `?? {}` work? Could you show some explenation?

Comment: `...` will copy the original object, and `?? {}` will make `array1[i]` an empty object if there is no value for `array1[i]`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both have same lenghth and you are combining same index object in both array.
using spread(`...`) to combine two object and using `map` to create a new object

```js
var Profiles = [
{ 
 fieldname: 'Black',
 filename: 'Blackcolor1630667241215.JPEG',
},
{
  fieldname: 'Black',
  filename: 'Blackcolor1630667241217.JPEG',
},
{
  fieldname: 'White',
  filename: 'Whitecolor1630667241218.JPEG',
},
{
  fieldname: 'White',
  filename: 'Whitecolor1630667241219.JPEG',
 }
]

var productimg = [{
  keyId: 0,
  objId: 0,
  fieldname: 'Black'
 },
{
  keyId: 1,
  objId: 0,
  fieldname: 'Black'
},
{
  keyId: 0,
  objId: 1,
  fieldname: 'White'
},
{
  keyId: 1,
  objId: 1,
  fieldname: 'White'
}]

let result =  Profiles.map((profile, index) => {
return {...profile, ...productimg[index] }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is not correct, it will only works if they are sorted with the same fieldnames...

Comment: hi vaira, thank you for your ans, but this is not what I'm looking for. i want to show all 4 object elements in final array

Comment: @CodeBug it will print all 4 if you use your array, i am only using a shorter array of length 2 to keep answer small

Comment: @Alexis he is actually not matching by fieldNames as in his example they are not unique
in his example

Comment: @vaira they don't need to be unique to match... take a look at my answer

Comment: @Alexis you answer is actually incorrect since it would always match with the first instance every single time.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to differentiate between matching based on *order* and matching based on *properties*. Though your objects have matching `fieldname` properties, you are matching based on order because there are mutliple entries with the same `fieldname` property.

Although most of the other answers work I think this will be the fastest.

```js
var Profiles = [{ fieldname: 'Black',filename: 'Blackcolor1630667241215.JPEG',},{fieldname: 'Black',filename: 'Blackcolor1630667241217.JPEG',},{fieldname: 'White',filename: 'Whitecolor1630667241218.JPEG',},{fieldname: 'White',filename: 'Whitecolor1630667241219.JPEG',}];
var productimg = [{keyId: 0,objId: 0,fieldname: 'Black'},{keyId: 1,objId: 0,fieldname: 'Black'},{keyId: 0,objId: 1,fieldname: 'White'},{keyId: 1,objId: 1,fieldname: 'White'}];

function mergeArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) return; // stop if different lengths
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i in arr1) // for each index
    newArr.push({ ...arr1[i], ...arr2[i] }); // combine the properties of both arrays to make a new object and add it to `newArr`
  return newArr;
}

console.log( mergeArrays( Profiles, productimg ) );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%} /* format console output */
```

Answer (score 1):

Just map from `Profiles`, merge from nodes in `productimg`

```js
var Profiles = [
  {
    fieldname: 'Black',
    filename: 'Blackcolor1630667241215.JPEG',
  },
  {
    fieldname: 'Black',
    filename: 'Blackcolor1630667241217.JPEG',
  },
  {
    fieldname: 'White',
    filename: 'Whitecolor1630667241218.JPEG',
  },
  {
    fieldname: 'White',
    filename: 'Whitecolor1630667241219.JPEG',
  }
]
var productimg = [{
  keyId: 0,
  objId: 0,
  fieldname: 'Black'
},
{
  keyId: 1,
  objId: 0,
  fieldname: 'Black'
},
{
  keyId: 0,
  objId: 1,
  fieldname: 'White'
},
{
  keyId: 1,
  objId: 1,
  fieldname: 'White'
}]

  const finalarray = Profiles.map((node, index) => {
    return { ...node, ...productimg[index] };
  });
  console.log(finalarray)
```